# pandas: how replace string value from column by multi if condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace, conditional-statements

I need help for my problem. I try replace "pe60" with "pe61" in column "level_2" if have ("pe60" in column "level_2" and "b" in column "level_1") and the same replace "pe70" with "pe71" in column "level_2" if have ("pe70" in column "level_2" and "b" in column "level_1").
my try but not work is:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name': ['Tom','nick','krish','jack','bob'],
        'level_1': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b','a'],
        'level_2': ['pe60', 'pe70', 'pe71', 'pe60','pe60'],
        'level_3': [-2, -1, 4, 6,-4],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

def f(row):
    if (row['level_2'] == 'pe60') & (row['level_1'] == 'b'):
        val = (row['level_2'] == 'pe61')
    elif (row['level_2'] == 'pe70') & (row['level_1'] == 'b'):
        val = (row['level_2'] == 'pe71')
    else:
        val = row['level_2']
    return val
df['level_2'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print(df)
```

my solution must be:

```
data_sol = {'Name': ['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack','bob'],
        'level_1': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b','a'],
        'level_2': ['pe60', 'pe71', 'pe71', 'pe61','pe60'],
        'level_3': [-2, -1, 4, 6,-4],
        }

df_solution = pd.DataFrame(data_sol)
print(df_solution)
```

how can solve my problem ?

Comment: For this very specific example, you can probably solve it using a one-liner `df.where` statement. A bit hacky, but just so you know: something like `df["level_2"].where(df["level_1"] != "b", df["level_2"].str.replace("0", "1"))`

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that you are using the [bitwise `&` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#index-16), not the [logical `and` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#index-4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close! You want to return the value, not test for equality:

```
def f(row):
    if (row['level_2'] == 'pe60') & (row['level_1'] == 'b'):
        val = 'pe61'
    elif (row['level_2'] == 'pe70') & (row['level_1'] == 'b'):
        val = 'pe71'
    else:
        val = row['level_2']
    return val
```

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that you are using the [bitwise `&` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#index-16), not the [logical `and` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#index-4)?

Comment: Logical and would be better; for single boolean values the two should reduce to the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.  Here's one way.

```python
def my_func(x):
     return [
              x[0],
              x[1],
              "pe61" if (x[1]=="b" and x[2]=="pe60") else ("pe71" if (x[1]=="b" and x[2]=="pe70") else x[2]),
              x[3]
            ]

fixed_df = df.apply(my_func, axis=1, raw=True)
```

The output:

```python
    Name level_1 level_2 level_3
0    Tom       a    pe60      -2
1   nick       b    pe71      -1
2  krish       a    pe71       4
3   jack       b    pe61       6
4    bob       a    pe60      -4
```

Here's another way.

```python
def my_func2(x):
     return "pe61" if (x[1]=="b" and x[2]=="pe60") else ("pe71" if (x[1]=="b" and x[2]=="pe70") else x[2])

df["level_2"] = df.apply(my_func2, axis=1, raw=True)
```

The *new* `df`:

```python
    Name level_1 level_2  level_3
0    Tom       a    pe60       -2
1   nick       b    pe71       -1
2  krish       a    pe71        4
3   jack       b    pe61        6
4    bob       a    pe60       -4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!! For me the first one (my_Func ) dont work ...take a second look

Comment: The output in the answer is _literally_ the output using your `df`.  What version of `python` and `pandas` are you using?  Or perhaps you just want `df = df.apply(my_func, axis=1, raw=True)`?

Comment: I try it to online python interpreter (programiz) and dont work . I dont try to my pycharm.

Comment: It works for me. https://programiz.pro/learn/python/online-ide/S8BT0DB25S?utm_source=programiz_dot_com_python_compiler_save_button

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas built-in functions and a dictionary if you have multiple such mappings:

```
mappings = {'pe60': 'pe61', 
            'pe70': 'pe71'}
df.loc[(df['level_2'].isin(mappings.keys())) & (df['level_1'] == 'b'), 'level_2'] = df['level_2'].map(mappings)

#df

    Name    level_1 level_2 level_3
0   Tom     a       pe60    -2
1   nick    b       pe71    -1
2   krish   a       pe71    4
3   jack    b       pe61    6
4   bob     a       pe60    -4
```

Please note that this check conditional value of `'level_1` against a constant value of `'b'`. If this value is also dependent on the `'level_2'`, the solution will be slightly different.